# Grab the first row that causes the sum of the previous rows to be greater that 10

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around when it comes to creating an effective SQL.

Below is the mysql setup:

```
id | countValue | name
 1 |    1       | b
 2 |    1       | b
 3 |    4       | b
 4 |    6       | b
 5 |    1       | b
```

What I am looking to do is grab the earliest row that the sum(countValue) of the previous rows (ORDER BY id DESC) become greater than 10

So in this case it would return: 3

It would return 3 because:

5.countValue + 4.countValue + 3.countValue = 12

So it would return id=3

My initial try:

```
 SELECT id FROM user WHERE sum(countValue) > 3 ORDER by id DESC
```

Then I changed to:

```
  SELECT id From users WHERE HAVING SUM(countValue) > 10 ORDER BY id DESC
```

The second one will only return the id if the individual countValue has more than 10 in it. Where I need the sum of the previous values which is why I am stuck.

Hope this makes sense and would love any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Not clear on question it self!! please refactor the question.

Comment: @Biswabid not sure how I can refactor this question. What part do you not understand? I gave examples and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a cumulative or running sum.  In MySQL, the best way to do this uses variables:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, (@s := @s + countValue) as runningCV
      from users u cross join
           (select @s := 0) params
      order by u.id desc
     ) u
where runningCV - countValue <= 10 and runningCV > 10;
```

The variable `@s` is used to calculate the cumulative sum.  The outer `where` clause returns the first value that crosses the "10" threshold.

You can also do this with a correlated subquery.  Unless your data is small, though, that will be expensive.

Comment: worked perfect! Thank you very much! I hadn't dug into an increment type system before. Thank you!